# Rails simple_form enum_help select lists issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, enums, simple-form

Im having an issue creating working selects for enum fields in my views using [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/)

Here's my code:

```
# In model project.rb

enum status: [:draft, :published]

# In view _form.html.erb

<%= simple_form_for @project do |f| %>

  <%= f.input :title %>

  <%= f.input :status %>

  ...

<% end %>
```

This is outputting a HTML5 number (integer increment) field instead of a select.

If I change to:

```
...
<%= f.input :status, as: :select %>
or
<%= f.input :status, as: :radio_buttons %>
...
```

It outputs a select list / radio buttons with the labels "Yes" and "No". When I attempt to save I get an #{integer} is not a valid value error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd be best using [`collection_select`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select) / [`collection_radio_buttons`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_radio_buttons):

```
<%= simple_form_for @project do |f| %>

  <%= f.input :status, collection: Project.statuses, label_method: :first, value_method: :first, include_blank: false %>
  <%= f.input :status, collection: Project.statuses, label_method: :first, value_method: :first, as: :radio_buttons %>

<% end %>
```

---

To give context, [`enum`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) stands for **enumerator**.

It maps your options to numeric values `[0,1]`, allowing you to succinctly define pre-baked choices for your attributes.

The reason why you're getting `yes/no` and an `integer` field is because of the "value" of the statuses is the array `[0,1]`. Rails cannot tell the difference. However, using the above method, it *can*.

Comment: Perfect Richard (just missing a comma after label_method: :first). Thank you so much.